# How to reference variable from scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Version: 1.5.5

I have two arrays in my scope, let's call them:

```
$scope.array1 = [1,2,3,4];
$scope.array2 = [5,6,7,8];
```

I want to modify one of this arrays based on a condition, for this I want to use the ternary conditional because I'll make changes on the array in different parts of my code, thus I'll avoid repeating the condition multiple times:

```
var header = (myCondition)?$scope.array1:$scope.array2;
header = [];
header.push(10);
//some code
header.push(11);
```

But this is not working! The changes on `header` are not reflected on the object in the $scope.

So I have to do this:

```
if(myCondition){
  $scope.array1 = [];
  $scope.array1.push(10);
}
else{
 $scope.array2 = [];
 $scope.array2.push(10);
}
//some code
if(myCondition){
 $scope.array1.push(11);
}
else{
 $scope.array2.push(11);
}
```

Which seems awful...

I think the first way should really work because `header` will keep the reference to the object in the $scope. Anyway, that was the dummy code to make my point, here is the real code (sorry if it's awful. My first time with Javascript):

```
$scope.getHeaders = function(type){
    req = createJsonedFilters(false, true, true);
    req['type'] = type;
    $http.post("/getHeaders", req).then(
        function(res){
            data = res.data;
            if(data['msg'] == "OK"){
                var minmax = (type == 'epidem')?"epidemMinMax":"entomoMinMax";
                var headers = (type == 'epidem')?$scope.epidemHeaders:$scope.entomoHeaders;
                headers = [];
                data_minmax = data[minmax]
                minmax_headers = Object.keys(data_minmax).sort();
                console.log(minmax_headers);
                for(var i=0; i < minmax_headers.length; i++){
                    var minmax_name = minmax_headers[i];
                    var mm_elem = data_minmax[minmax_name]
                    var atributo = {
                      name: minmax_name,
                      enabled: true,
                      slider: {minValue: parseInt(mm_elem['min']), maxValue: parseInt(mm_elem['max']),
                               options: {floor: parseInt(mm_elem['min']),ceil: parseInt(mm_elem['max']),
                               step: 1}}
                    };
                    headers.push(atributo);
                }
                console.log(headers);
                $scope.refreshAttributes();
            }
            else{
                console.log('Empty ' + type + ' Dataset...')
            }
        },
        function(){
            console.log("Couldn't load " + type + " headers...")
        }
    );
}
```

Any ideas why the reference to headers won't modify the object in the scope? If there is any output I can give you, comment and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrays are `properties` of the `$scope` object. You can thus access them using their `key` with the syntax `$scope[arrayName]` (where arrayName is a `string`).

Therefore, using `myCondition`, you have to store the name of the array you want to modify in a variable that you'll use in the following steps.

```
var arrayName = (myCondition) ? 'array1' : 'array2';
$scope[arrayName] = [];
$scope[arrayName].push(10);
//some code
$scope[arrayName].push(11);
```

**EDIT**

Your code doesn't work because you erase the reference to the `$scope.array1` by creating a new array (`header = []`).

You could copy the content of the `header` array into the appropriate array of your `$scope` after all the operations are made.

```
var header = [];
header.push(10);
//some code
header.push(11);

if (myCondition) {
    $scope.array1 = header;
} else {
    $scope.array2 = header;
}
```

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: Will try this. But could you please explain why is this the way to do it? Nevermind, just saw you added it.

Comment: This answer is already correct, but why doesn't the other, the most common and natural way doesn't work? Is this a Javascript or AngularJS thing?

Comment: @AFP_555 Please check the answer with explanation for why `headers` way was not working. Do let me know whether it clarifies your doubt?

Comment: @AFP_555 I've updated my answer by adding explanation why your code does not work

Comment: Hmmm... Actually it does get the reference to the object. It's proven in this plunker when I reference the var tmp with the scope. It holds the reference. https://plnkr.co/edit/Cr5CC5aBl7xWODvvqSw2?p=preview , but still, thank you for your answer and your solution is the way I'll use.

Comment: Based on my findings, I'll explain why between the two answers I consider this the solution. What I found here: http://2ality.com/2012/12/clear-array.html shows that the common way of clearing and array is referencing a new object. The way that lets you clear an array and keep the reference to the object is time costly and should be avoided, thus, accessing the elements in the scope directly by name should be the fastest way to clear the array without missing the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is was not working with the reference for `headers` is when you assign appropriate array via

```
var headers = (type == 'epidem')?$scope.epidemHeaders:$scope.entomoHeaders;
```

Now the `headers` will hold the reference for either of the `$scope.epidemHeaders` or `$scope.entomoHeaders` array(as array is also an object).

And when you try to assign the new array to `headers` via `headers = []`. The `headers` now holds new reference, not either of the `$scope.epidemHeaders` or `$scope.entomoHeaders` array. i.e `headers` will be pointing to different array, whereas say `$scope.epidemHeaders = [1,2,3,4]` and `$scope.entomoHeaders = [5,6,7,8]`

Hence pushing to `headers` after assigning new array wont push the element to the array on the `$scope`. In fact it adds to the new array. Hence the changes weren't reflected.

If you still want to use the `header` ways of reference, try pushing the element without setting the new array.

Or if resetting is your case then use the below mentioned way:

```
var headers = (type == 'epidem')?$scope.epidemHeaders:$scope.entomoHeaders;
headers.length = 0; // Trick to reset the array retaining the same reference
headers.push(11);
```

Comment: Hmm... This is correct. I didn't realize [ ] created a new object. I thought it was the way to clear the array. Not sure what is the right thing to do here as the previous answer also solved my problem. But I feel this is the root of the problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks. It's sad there is no way to clear an array in an elegant way without missing the reference  to the object... or I haven't found one.

Comment: There is no method available to do that. But you can use one trick, i.e. by setting the length of the array to 0. I have updated the answer with this solution. Do give a try.